# N body ODE simulation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I have been staring at the below matlab code, which simulates planetary motion, for a while now and I could really use a fresh set of eyes. I cannot understand why it is giving straight line trajectories for the planets' motion. All the initial data has been taken from Geometric Numerical Integration by Hairer Pg. 13. Thanks for your help.

For the Hamiltonian
$$H(q,p) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\|p_n\|^2}{m_n} -G \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=n+1}^N \frac{m_n m_j}{\|q_n -q_j\|}$$
equation of motion of the planets are
$$\frac{dq_n}{dt} = \frac{p_n}{m_n},\\
\frac{dp_n}{dt} = -G\sum_{j \neq n} \frac{m_n m_j}{\|q_n -q_j\|^3}(q_n-q_j)$$
which gives the following Stormer-Verlet method ($i$ is the time index)
$$p_n^{i+1/2} = p_n^i -\frac{\Delta t}{2}G\sum_{j \neq n} \frac{m_n m_j}{\|q_n^i -q_j^i\|^3}(q_n^i-q_j^i),\\
q_n^{i+1} = q_n^i + \Delta t \frac{p_n^{i+1/2}}{m_n},\\
p_n^{i+1} = p_n^{i+1/2} -\frac{\Delta t}{2}G\sum_{j \neq n} \frac{m_n m_j}{\|q_n^{i+1} -q_j^{i+1}\|^3}(q_n^{i+1}-q_j^{i+1}).$$

```
    function NbodyODE(dt, T, N, q0, p0, m, G)
    % This function solves NbodyODE with symplectic Stormer-Verlet method

if nargin < 1, dt = 10; end                 % one time step-size is equal to 10 earth days
if nargin < 2, T = 200000; end              % simulate outer solar system for 200 000 earth days
if nargin < 3, N = 6; end
if nargin < 4, q0 = [0 0 0;                 % initial positions of the planets, the Sun is at (0,0,0)
                    -3.5023653 -3.8169847 -1.5507963;
                     9.0755314 -3.0458353 -1.6483708;
                     8.3101420 -16.2901086 -7.2521278;
                     11.4707666 -25.7294829 -10.8169456;
                     -15.5387357 -25.2225594 -3.1902382
                    ]; end
if nargin < 5, p0 = [0 0 0;                 % initial momenta of the planets
                    0.00565429 -0.00412490 -0.00190589;
                     0.00168318 0.00483525 0.00192462;
                     0.00354178 0.00137102 0.00055029;
                     0.00288930 0.00114527 0.00039677;
                     0.00276725 -0.00170702 -0.00136504
                    ]; end
if nargin < 6, m = [1.00000597682;          % masses of the solar bodies.
                    0.000954786104043;
                     0.000285583733151;
                     0.0000437273164546;
                     0.0000517759138449;
                     1/1.3e8
                    ]; end
if nargin < 7, G = 2.95912208286e-4; end    % Gravitational constant

if (size(q0,1) ~= N || size(p0,1) ~= N || size(m,1) ~= N)
    error('input dimensions mismatch, correct input data')
end

t = 0:dt:T;
L = length(t);
q = zeros(N,3,L); p = q; q(:,:,1) = q0; p(:,:,1) = p0;

[q1, p1] = SV(m, dt, L, N, q, p, G);

for n = 1:N
    x = reshape(q1(n,1,:),L,1); y = reshape(q1(n,2,:),L,1); z = reshape(q1(n,3,:),L,1);
    plot3(x,y,z), hold on
end

function [q, p]= SV(m, dt, L, N, q, p, G)
    Vf = @(m1,m2,x,y) (G*m1*m2*(x-y)/(norm(x-y))^3);

tau = zeros(N,3,L);
for n = 1:N
    for j = [1:n-1 n+1:N]
        tau(n,:,1) = tau(n,:,1) + Vf(m(n), m(j), q(n,:,1), q(j,:,1));
    end
end

for i = 1:L-1
    for n = 1:N
        p(n,:,i+1) = p(n,:,i) - dt/2*tau(n,:,i);
        q(n,:,i+1) = q(n,:,i) + dt/m(n)*p(n,:,i+1);
    end

    for n = 1:N
        for j = [1:n-1 n+1:N]
            tau(n,:,i+1) = tau(n,:,i+1) + Vf(m(n), m(j), q(n,:,i+1), q(j,:,i+1));
        end
    end

    for n = 1:N
        p(n,:,i+1) = p(n,:,i+1) - dt/2*tau(n,:,i+1);
    end
end
```

Comment: Your code is not runnable unless you provide inputs to `NbodyODE(dt, T, N, q0, p0, m, G)` that reproduce the issue in question. Or does just `NbodyODE()` not work (in that case you should simplify your code for this question)?.

Comment: @horchler, you don't have to provide any input arguments to this code. Just type NbodyODE on the command line or simply press F5 (with control over the editor). It has all the input it needs built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### On the proper way to implement the Verlet method

You need to first compute all interaction forces, and only after all forces have been computed can you update the position vector. Not doing this and mixing interaction with position updates usually results in an unphysical drift.

You should store the forces or acceleration in an extra array, at the moment you are computing the forces for each computation twice.

```
p(i+1) = p(i)+f(i) * dt/2
q(i+1) = q(i)+p(i)/m * dt
f(i+1) = forces(q(i+1))
p(i+1) = p(i+1)+f(i+1) * dt/2
```

One does not need to keep a history of the force terms, one can always use the same array (if one were implementing the method with fine-tuned memory management).

### Improved Verlet method - Verlet4

Also try out the "improved" Verlet method where you chain

```
Verlet(b0*dt); Verlet(-b1*dt); Verlet(b0*dt)
```

for one time step `dt` with `b0=1/(2-2^(1/3))=1.35120719196` and `b1=2*b0-1=1.70241438392`. It should be in the book under "composition methods" or "methods obtained by composition". It gives you a 4th order method for little extra programming effort.

---

### How to initialize and avoid drift of the system

Study the implementation in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/odeint/examples/solar_system.cpp, especially the initialization. The total impulse of the system is not zero. The second set of vectors is not the initial impulse but the initial velocity, so they need to be converted to impulses. Do this via

```
pmean = zeros(1,3); qmean = pmean; tmass = 0;
for n=1:N
    pmean = pmean + p0(n,:)*mass(n);
    qmean = qmean + q0(n,:)*mass(n);
    tmass = tmass + mass(n);
end
qmean = qmean / tmass; pmean = pmean / tmass
for n=1:N
    q0(n,:) = q0(n,:) - qmean;
    p0(n,:) = (p0(n,:) - pmean)*mass(n);
end
```

Comment: Thanks @LutzL. I made the changes as per your suggestions but I am still getting straight line trajectories. Please see the new code above.

Comment: Now you set for every particle the force array to zero. Put the initialization of `tau` outside of the loops.

Comment: @user30850: Try shorter time spans, 1 to 10 years. The straight lines you see is just the escape to infinity essentially without interaction. Since in the now second version of the code the only interaction that survives is the other planets acting on Pluto, straight lines are to be expected.

Comment: I initialized `tau` outside of all the loops but I still get straight line trajectories. I checked the value of position array `q` at `i=2` and I get huge numbers:
q(:,:,2) =
1.0e+06 *
-0.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000
0.0001 -0.0000 -0.0000
0.0001 0.0002 0.0001
0.0008 0.0003 0.0001
0.0006 0.0002 0.0001
3.5974 -2.2192 -1.7746
 This means the trajectories are wrong even for shorter time spans. Thanks for your help @LutzL.

Comment: @user30850: The initialization is more complex than copying the values. In the book the velocities are given, center-of-mass and zero-total-impulse has to be established, it is not given in the data. See new addition to answer. Scilab translation of the code now works.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!